# Capital Letters translating from english to japanese, help?

Tags: translation, kanji

Hello I have been on google translate this morning and realised that if I translate two words first without capital letters and then with capital letters at the beginning of each word like you would a name, the Japanese translation changes significantly, so is there a correct or incorrect translation, does the Japanese language use capital letters? can someone please explain the difference in the translations below. Also I understand that there are different japanese scripts, if possible could someone please show me what the correct translation for Kaido Works looks like in those different scripts. Thank You, K

kaido works   カイドー作品  Kaidō sakuhin ------
Kaido Works  カイドーワークス Kaidōwākusu

Answer (score 3):

Japanese language does not have capital letters like what you have in English.

Google expects you obey the standard English formatting. If you capitalize each word in English, the machine generally tries to translate it as a proper noun (in this case, a company name). If you don't capitalize, it tries to understand the phrase as a normal noun phrase. カイドー作品 is a normal noun phrase that means "works created by Kaido", while カイドーワークス looks like a valid company name. I don't know what you really mean by "Kaido Works", so I don't know which is the better translation, either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of capital letters in Japanese. I think when google sees a capital letter is is probably treating it as a proper noun.

カイドーワークス is in the katakana script and it is a direct rendering (at least as direct as possible) of the English pronunciation.

作品 is kanji. It means 'work' as in the work of a film director, author.

I have no idea what 'Kaido Works' is. There isn't a unique 'correct' Japanese phrase that would yield this English transliteration. Google Translate will certainly not help you with this.

Comment: Yes, we would need more context. Many interpretations are possible... "かいどう君働いているんだ！" - "カイドウ...動くぞ" might also work :)